# edit update existing array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am making CRUD app for learning purpose. I need to update existing javascript array on click of edit button. However currently its not updating the existing array rather then its creating new record. Below is the JS code of controller

For **Add screen** below is the controller code

```
.controller('addController', ['$scope','$location','$rootScope', function(scope,location,rootScope){

    scope.save = function (){
        scope.personName = document.getElementById('name').value;
        scope.personDesc = document.getElementById('desc').value;

        scope.person = {'name' : scope.personName, 'desc' : scope.personDesc};

        if(typeof rootScope.crew === 'undefined'){
            rootScope.crew = [];
        }
        rootScope.crew.push(scope.person);
        location.path("/");
    }
}])
```

For Edit Screen, below is the code of controller :-

```
.controller('editController',['$scope','$location','$routeParams','$rootScope', function(scope,location,routeParams,rootScope){
    var oldName = scope.crew[routeParams.id].name;


    document.getElementById('name').value = scope.crew[routeParams.id].name;
    document.getElementById('desc').value = scope.crew[routeParams.id].desc;

    scope.editSave = function(){
        scope.person = {
            'name' : document.getElementById('name').value, 
            'desc' : document.getElementById('desc').value
        }

        rootScope.crew.push(scope.person);
        location.path("/");
    }
}])
```

Currently I am adding record in existing array rather updating.

Please suggest

Comment: Hi @Anand deep Singh, you need to paste entire JS and HTML code to give clarity to stackoverflow users. Just pasting array information is not sufficient.

Comment: Do not use DOM manipulation in controllers. Instead use ng-model in your templates to bind the form fields to your controller

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are pushing a new item to the array. You need to just update the existing person with the person in scope.

```
.controller('editController',['$scope','$location','$routeParams','$rootScope', function(scope,location,routeParams,rootScope){
    var person = scope.crew[routeParams.id]

    scope.person = {
        name = person.name,
        desc = person.desc
    };

    scope.editSave = function(){
        scope.crew[routeParams.id] = scope.person;
        location.path("/");
    }
}])
```

In your edit view you would have this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" ng-model="person.name"/>
<input type="text" id="desc" ng-model="person.desc"/>
```

It's also worth mentioning that there is no need to have code such as `document.getElementById` as angular will handle the model binding for you so you don't have to interact with the dom using javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Every object that you are pushing in array must be identified by some id.So assign one id attribute to the person object that you are pushing.

Now come to the edit.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in person">
{{p.name}}

//In button  I am passing id which I used in editing the person object
<button ng-click="edit(p.id)"></button> 
</tr>
//In controller
edit(id){
//firstly search for the person which is going to be updated
for(i=0;i<arrayInWhichYouArePushingData.length;i++)
  {   
     if(arrayInWhichYouArePushingData[i].id==id)
        {
         arrayInWhichYouArePushingData[i]=UpdatedData;
           break;
       }

  }
```

This is just an algorithm to solve this type of problem.You have to modify little bit.